# A question about $PSL(2,8)$

Tags: finite-groups

Can anybody tell me how to construct the character table of $PSL(2,8)$?

I need a specific method.

Comment: If you just need the character table, not the derivation or a description
of each irreducible representation, you can find it in the ATLAS because
the group is simple.

Comment: Or, you can use GAP for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The character tables of $PSL(2,q)$, $SL(2,q)$, $PGL(2,q)$ and $GL2(,q)$ have been computed. For the result and a specific method see for example here: http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jda/characters/characters.pdf